# Analyse crash log

Tags: iphone, crash-reports

Can anyone help in identifying the issue through below crash log? These are the symblicated crash logs and I know these are symbolicated since last 2 lines of thread 0 point to main

```
   35  MyApp                   0x00002dd6 main (main.m:14)
   36  MyApp                   0x00002da0 start + 32



    Incident Identifier: 55B520ED-88BA-4868-B667-300312067482
    CrashReporter Key:   e008134806f5c66b2b3f7044e6ce23e658ef0bfc
    Hardware Model:      iPad1,1
    Process:         MyApp [865]
    Path:            /var/mobile/Applications/7D89559C-54D6-4F5D-BB0E-FABA4E0AC079/MyApp.app/MyApp
    Identifier:      MyApp
    Version:         ??? (???)
    Code Type:       ARM (Native)
    Parent Process:  launchd [1]

    Date/Time:       2011-05-09 08:12:30.237 -0700
    OS Version:      iPhone OS 4.2.1 (8C148)
    Report Version:  104

    Exception Type:  EXC_BAD_ACCESS (SIGSEGV)
    Exception Codes: KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS at 0xfdfffefe
    Crashed Thread:  0

    Thread 0 Crashed:
    0   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x34a80462 objc_msgSend + 14
    1   UIKit                           0x341aab5c _UIView + 52
    2   UIKit                           0x341aaaa8 -[UIView(Hierarchy) _makeSubtreePerformSelector:withObject:withObject:copySublayers:] + 152
    3   UIKit                           0x341aa9fe -[UIView(Hierarchy) _makeSubtreePerformSelector:withObject:] + 22
    4   UIKit                           0x341c0600 -[UIView(Hierarchy) removeFromSuperview] + 304
    5   UIKit                           0x341c6328 -[UIView dealloc] + 148
    6   UIKit                           0x34224e72 -[UILayoutContainerView dealloc] + 54
    7   CoreFoundation                  0x357e0f74 -[NSObject(NSObject) release] + 24
    8   UIKit                           0x342246b2 -[UINavigationController _releaseContainerViews] + 66
    9   UIKit                           0x342e5d10 -[UINavigationController viewDidUnload] + 8
    10  UIKit                           0x3424847e -[UIViewController unloadViewForced:] + 166
    11  UIKit                           0x342483ca -[UIViewController unloadViewIfReloadable] + 10
    12  UIKit                           0x342e1dde -[UIViewController purgeMemoryForReason:] + 34
    13  UIKit                           0x342e5d36 -[UINavigationController purgeMemoryForReason:] + 26
    14  UIKit                           0x342e1dfe -[UIViewController didReceiveMemoryWarning] + 10
    15  UIKit                           0x342e1e14 -[UIViewController _didReceiveMemoryWarning:] + 8
    16  Foundation                      0x3117561c _nsnote_callback + 136
    17  CoreFoundation                  0x3580111c __CFXNotificationPost_old + 396
    18  CoreFoundation                  0x35800dbc _CFXNotificationPostNotification + 112
    19  Foundation                      0x31164d1c -[NSNotificationCenter postNotificationName:object:userInfo:] + 64
    20  Foundation                      0x3116e23a -[NSNotificationCenter postNotificationName:object:] + 18
    21  UIKit                           0x342aada2 -[UIApplication _performMemoryWarning] + 42
    22  UIKit                           0x342ab9c4 -[UIApplication _receivedMemoryNotification] + 120
    23  UIKit                           0x342a8770 _memoryStatusChanged + 36
    24  CoreFoundation                  0x358310c6 __CFNotificationCenterDarwinCallBack + 18
    25  CoreFoundation                  0x35817be0 __CFMachPortPerform + 204
    26  CoreFoundation                  0x3580f6f8 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE1_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 20
    27  CoreFoundation                  0x3580f6bc __CFRunLoopDoSource1 + 160
    28  CoreFoundation                  0x35801f76 __CFRunLoopRun + 514
    29  CoreFoundation                  0x35801c80 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 224
    30  CoreFoundation                  0x35801b88 CFRunLoopRunInMode + 52
    31  GraphicsServices                0x320c84a4 GSEventRunModal + 108
    32  GraphicsServices                0x320c8550 GSEventRun + 56
    33  UIKit                           0x341dc322 -[UIApplication _run] + 406
    34  UIKit                           0x341d9e8c UIApplicationMain + 664
    35  MyApp                   0x00002dd6 main (main.m:14)
    36  MyApp                   0x00002da0 start + 32

    Thread 1:
    0   libSystem.B.dylib               0x30d30974 kevent + 24
    1   libSystem.B.dylib               0x30dda704 _dispatch_mgr_invoke + 88
    2   libSystem.B.dylib               0x30dda174 _dispatch_queue_invoke + 96
    3   libSystem.B.dylib               0x30dd9b98 _dispatch_worker_thread2 + 120
    4   libSystem.B.dylib               0x30d7e24a _pthread_wqthread + 258
    5   libSystem.B.dylib               0x30d76970 start_wqthread + 0

    Thread 2:
    0   libCGFreetype.A.dylib           0x354ac650 FT_Open_Face + 0
    1   libCGFreetype.A.dylib           0x354a0998 (anonymous namespace)::open_face(FT::stream*, long, __CFString const*) + 108
    2   libCGFreetype.A.dylib           0x354a0b9a FT::font::create_fonts_with_path(__CFString const*) + 94
    3   libCGFreetype.A.dylib           0x354a8c22 (anonymous namespace)::create_private_data_with_path(__CFString const*) + 70
    4   CoreGraphics                    0x30415ea6 CGFontCreateFontsWithPath + 18
    5   CoreGraphics                    0x30415de8 add_fonts_at_path_locked + 36
    6   CoreGraphics                    0x30410fa8 CGFontDBGetFontWithName + 72
    7   CoreGraphics                    0x30410e78 CGFontCreateWithFontName + 48
    8   CoreGraphics                    0x30410e30 CGFontCreateWithName + 20
    9   GraphicsServices                0x320c7346 GSFontCreateWithName + 278
    10  WebCore                         0x34b91f56 +[WebFontCache createFontWithFamily:traits:weight:size:] + 22
    11  WebCore                         0x34b91cea WebCore::FontCache::createFontPlatformData(WebCore::FontDescription const&, WebCore::AtomicString const&) + 358
    12  WebCore                         0x34b918a6 WebCore::FontCache::getCachedFontPlatformData(WebCore::FontDescription const&, WebCore::AtomicString const&, bool) + 226
    13  WebCore                         0x34b91a70 WebCore::FontCache::getCachedFontPlatformData(WebCore::FontDescription const&, WebCore::AtomicString const&, bool) + 684
    14  WebCore                         0x34b911b8 WebCore::FontCache::getFontData(WebCore::Font const&, int&, WebCore::FontSelector*) + 100
    15  WebCore                         0x34b41ce4 WebCore::FontFallbackList::fontDataAt(WebCore::Font const*, unsigned int) const + 48
    16  WebCore                         0x34b910a6 WebCore::RenderBlock::lineHeight(bool, bool) const + 146
    17  WebCore                         0x34bc1036 WebCore::InlineFlowBox::computeLogicalBoxHeights(int&, int&, int&, int&, bool) + 46
    18  WebCore                         0x34bc0f98 WebCore::RootInlineBox::verticallyAlignBoxes(int) + 88
    19  WebCore                         0x34bc0ef4 WebCore::RenderBlock::computeVerticalPositionsForLine(WebCore::RootInlineBox*, WebCore::BidiRun*) + 16
    20  WebCore                         0x34b90656 WebCore::RenderBlock::layoutInlineChildren(bool, int&, int&) + 2714
    21  WebCore                         0x34b8d7e0 WebCore::RenderBlock::layoutBlock(bool) + 668
    22  WebCore                         0x34b8d520 WebCore::RenderBlock::layout() + 20
    23  WebCore                         0x34b8ee82 WebCore::RenderBlock::layoutBlockChild(WebCore::RenderBox*, WebCore::RenderBlock::MarginInfo&, int&, int&) + 386
    24  WebCore                         0x34b8e7c0 WebCore::RenderBlock::layoutBlockChildren(bool, int&) + 384
    25  WebCore                         0x34b8d7ee WebCore::RenderBlock::layoutBlock(bool) + 682
    26  WebCore                         0x34b8d520 WebCore::RenderBlock::layout() + 20
    27  WebCore                         0x34b8ee82 WebCore::RenderBlock::layoutBlockChild(WebCore::RenderBox*, WebCore::RenderBlock::MarginInfo&, int&, int&) + 386
    28  WebCore                         0x34b8e7c0 WebCore::RenderBlock::layoutBlockChildren(bool, int&) + 384
    29  WebCore                         0x34b8d7ee WebCore::RenderBlock::layoutBlock(bool) + 682
    30  WebCore                         0x34b8d520 WebCore::RenderBlock::layout() + 20
    31  WebCore                         0x34b8d4be WebCore::RenderView::layout() + 310
    32  WebCore                         0x34b8a3f2 WebCore::FrameView::layout(bool) + 1398
    33  WebCore                         0x34bfe6a8 WebCore::Document::implicitClose() + 792
    34  WebCore                         0x34bfe388 WebCore::FrameLoader::checkCallImplicitClose() + 80
    35  WebCore                         0x34bfe2a0 WebCore::FrameLoader::checkCompleted() + 128
    36  WebCore                         0x34bfdff6 WebCore::FrameLoader::finishedParsing() + 58
    37  WebCore                         0x34bfdf70 WebCore::Document::finishedParsing() + 168
    38  WebCore                         0x34bd8054 WebCore::HTMLParser::finished() + 128
    39  WebCore                         0x34bd7408 WebCore::HTMLTokenizer::end() + 104
    40  WebCore                         0x34bd737e WebCore::HTMLTokenizer::finish() + 754
    41  WebCore                         0x34bfda3a WebCore::Document::finishParsing() + 14
    42  WebCore                         0x34bfb1a8 WebCore::DocumentWriter::endIfNotLoadingMainResource() + 88
    43  WebCore                         0x34bfb140 WebCore::DocumentWriter::end() + 16
    44  WebCore                         0x34bf9320 WebCore::DocumentLoader::finishedLoading() + 40
    45  WebCore                         0x34c28f6a WebCore::FrameLoader::finishedLoading() + 46
    46  WebCore                         0x34c28ed2 WebCore::MainResourceLoader::didFinishLoading() + 34
    47  WebCore                         0x34c0bf12 WebCore::MainResourceLoader::continueAfterContentPolicy(WebCore::PolicyAction, WebCore::ResourceResponse const&) + 702
    48  WebCore                         0x34c0bc16 WebCore::MainResourceLoader::continueAfterContentPolicy(WebCore::PolicyAction) + 38
    49  WebCore                         0x34c0b7ae WebCore::MainResourceLoader::didReceiveResponse(WebCore::ResourceResponse const&) + 494
    50  WebCore                         0x34fbe32c WebCore::MainResourceLoader::handleDataLoadNow(WebCore::Timer<WebCore::MainResourceLoader>*) + 244
    51  WebCore                         0x34fbe5d4 WebCore::Timer<WebCore::MainResourceLoader>::fired() + 36
    52  WebCore                         0x34b89a5c WebCore::ThreadTimers::sharedTimerFiredInternal() + 88
    53  WebCore                         0x34b899f2 WebCore::ThreadTimers::sharedTimerFired() + 34
    54  WebCore                         0x34b899a6 WebCore::timerFired(__CFRunLoopTimer*, void*) + 34
    55  CoreFoundation                  0x3583109c __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_TIMER_CALLBACK_FUNCTION__ + 8
    56  CoreFoundation                  0x35830b54 __CFRunLoopDoTimer + 844
    57  CoreFoundation                  0x358021ae __CFRunLoopRun + 1082
    58  CoreFoundation                  0x35801c80 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 224
    59  CoreFoundation                  0x35801b88 CFRunLoopRunInMode + 52
    60  WebCore                         0x34bf6124 RunWebThread(void*) + 332
    61  libSystem.B.dylib               0x30d7d886 _pthread_start + 242
    62  libSystem.B.dylib               0x30d72a88 thread_start + 0

    Thread 3:
    0   libSystem.B.dylib               0x30d285e0 setsockopt + 20
    1   CFNetwork                       0x3064d732 _CFSocketSetNoDelay(__CFSocket*) + 22
    2   CFNetwork                       0x3064d28a SocketStream::createSocket_NoLock(__CFData const*) + 186
    3   CFNetwork                       0x3064cf2e SocketStream::attemptNextConnection_NoLock() + 178
    4   CFNetwork                       0x3064cbe4 SocketStream::hostCallback(__CFHost*, CFHostInfoType, CFStreamError const*) + 152
    5   CFNetwork                       0x306c771c SocketStream::_HostCallBack(__CFHost*, CFHostInfoType, CFStreamError const*, SocketStream*) + 36
    6   CFNetwork                       0x3064c87c Host::performCallback(InheritEnum<_ExtendedHostInfoType, CFHostInfoType>) + 100
    7   CFNetwork                       0x3064c80c Host::performCallback(InheritEnum<_ExtendedHostInfoType, CFHostInfoType>, void const*) + 40
    8   CFNetwork                       0x3064c7a0 HostLookup_Master::getAddrInfoCallback(int, addrinfo*) + 172
    9   CFNetwork                       0x3064c6ea HostLookup_Master::_GetAddrInfoCallBack(int, addrinfo*, void*) + 14
    10  libSystem.B.dylib               0x30d32012 si_libinfo_addrinfo_callback + 114
    11  libSystem.B.dylib               0x30d31f66 si_async_handle_reply + 38
    12  libSystem.B.dylib               0x30d31f36 getaddrinfo_async_handle_reply + 2
    13  CFNetwork                       0x306d75c6 HostLookup_Master::getAddrInfoMachPortCallback(__CFMachPort*, void*) + 30
    14  CFNetwork                       0x306d759e HostLookup_Master::_GetAddrInfoMachPortCallBack(__CFMachPort*, void*, long, void*) + 14
    15  CoreFoundation                  0x35817be0 __CFMachPortPerform + 204
    16  CoreFoundation                  0x3580f6f8 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE1_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 20
    17  CoreFoundation                  0x3580f6bc __CFRunLoopDoSource1 + 160
    18  CoreFoundation                  0x35801f76 __CFRunLoopRun + 514
    19  CoreFoundation                  0x35801c80 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 224
    20  CoreFoundation                  0x35801b88 CFRunLoopRunInMode + 52
    21  Foundation                      0x3118e5f6 +[NSURLConnection(NSURLConnectionReallyInternal) _resourceLoadLoop:] + 206
    22  Foundation                      0x3116c192 -[NSThread main] + 38
    23  Foundation                      0x31165242 __NSThread__main__ + 966
    24  libSystem.B.dylib               0x30d7d886 _pthread_start + 242
    25  libSystem.B.dylib               0x30d72a88 thread_start + 0

    Thread 4:
    0   libSystem.B.dylib               0x30d2868c select$DARWIN_EXTSN + 20
    1   CoreFoundation                  0x35839662 __CFSocketManager + 582
    2   libSystem.B.dylib               0x30d7d886 _pthread_start + 242
    3   libSystem.B.dylib               0x30d72a88 thread_start + 0

    Thread 5:
    0   libSystem.B.dylib               0x30d7e9e0 __workq_kernreturn + 8
    1   libSystem.B.dylib               0x30d7e364 _pthread_wqthread + 540
    2   libSystem.B.dylib               0x30d76970 start_wqthread + 0

    Thread 6:
    0   libSystem.B.dylib               0x30d7e9e0 __workq_kernreturn + 8
    1   libSystem.B.dylib               0x30d7e364 _pthread_wqthread + 540
    2   libSystem.B.dylib               0x30d76970 start_wqthread + 0

    Thread 7:
    0   libSystem.B.dylib               0x30d04268 mach_msg_trap + 20
    1   libSystem.B.dylib               0x30d06354 mach_msg + 44
    2   CoreFoundation                  0x35802648 __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 88
    3   CoreFoundation                  0x35801ed2 __CFRunLoopRun + 350
    4   CoreFoundation                  0x35801c80 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 224
    5   CoreFoundation                  0x35801b88 CFRunLoopRunInMode + 52
    6   CFNetwork                       0x306a8b24 CFURLConnectionSendSynchronousRequest + 244
    7   Foundation                      0x3120fcfc +[NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:returningResponse:error:] + 76
    8   AppSupport                      0x30835d62 downloadDictionary + 122
    9   AppSupport                      0x30835e60 -[PEPServiceConfiguration _updateDefaults:] + 76
    10  Foundation                      0x3116c192 -[NSThread main] + 38
    11  Foundation                      0x31165242 __NSThread__main__ + 966
    12  libSystem.B.dylib               0x30d7d886 _pthread_start + 242
    13  libSystem.B.dylib               0x30d72a88 thread_start + 0

    Thread 8:
    0   libSystem.B.dylib               0x30d04268 mach_msg_trap + 20
    1   libSystem.B.dylib               0x30d06354 mach_msg + 44
    2   libSystem.B.dylib               0x30d2efba si_async_launchpad + 174
    3   libSystem.B.dylib               0x30d7d886 _pthread_start + 242
    4   libSystem.B.dylib               0x30d72a88 thread_start + 0

    Thread 0 crashed with ARM Thread State:
    r0: 0xfdfffefe    r1: 0x344b6b50      r2: 0x3e8c4300      r3: 0x3e8c4300
    r4: 0xfdfffefe    r5: 0x3e8cb8b4      r6: 0x00000004      r7: 0x2fdfe8a0
    r8: 0x344bfef8    r9: 0x003fc098     r10: 0x00000000     r11: 0x344ba893
    ip: 0x3e82ac58    sp: 0x2fdfe888      lr: 0x341aab63      pc: 0x34a80462
    cpsr: 0xa0000030
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
2   UIKit                           0x341aaaa8 -[UIView(Hierarchy) _makeSubtreePerformSelector:withObject:withObject:copySublayers:] + 152
3   UIKit                           0x341aa9fe -[UIView(Hierarchy) _makeSubtreePerformSelector:withObject:] + 22
4   UIKit                           0x341c0600 -[UIView(Hierarchy) removeFromSuperview] + 304
5   UIKit                           0x341c6328 -[UIView dealloc] + 148
6   UIKit                           0x34224e72 -[UILayoutContainerView dealloc] + 54
7   CoreFoundation                  0x357e0f74 -[NSObject(NSObject) release] + 24
8   UIKit                           0x342246b2 -[UINavigationController _releaseContainerViews] + 66
9   UIKit                           0x342e5d10 -[UINavigationController viewDidUnload] + 8
10  UIKit                           0x3424847e -[UIViewController unloadViewForced:] + 166
11  UIKit                           0x342483ca -[UIViewController unloadViewIfReloadable] + 10
12  UIKit                           0x342e1dde -[UIViewController purgeMemoryForReason:] + 34
13  UIKit                           0x342e5d36 -[UINavigationController purgeMemoryForReason:] + 26
14  UIKit                           0x342e1dfe -[UIViewController didReceiveMemoryWarning] + 10
```

If you observe 14 number line it says didReceiveMemoryWarning.

Thanks,